# GCM Registration ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is GCM registration ID same for all the applications installed on device or is this unique for an app?

To be more specific, I have 10 applications installed on a device and all of them support push notifications. How many registration IDs will device have? 10 or 1?

Comment: It's unique for each application.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have 10. GCM generates a new token for every app you register even if it's on the same device.

Be also aware that GCM may generate a new token for your app depending on some events (app update for exemple). You may want to take a look at the documentation (the `onTokenRefresh` part): https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Answer (score 0):

It will generate one GCM id for each application.

Your GCM sender key is unique per app.

Comment: Thanks your reply,I feel GCM ID need not be unique for each application because we do define a permissions for broadcast receivers in application manifest file to identify who can receive a message and who can send a message and these permissions begin with application ID, which is again unique for each application. I'm confused because if GCM ID is unique for each application then why do we define permissions in manifest.

Comment: Those permissions that you set in manifest are to receive the messages and tell the app which service will be in charge of those, like any other intent filter. maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration)

> To register with GCM:
>
> The **client app** obtains a registration token using the Instance ID API.
>   The call to this API must have the authorized entity set to your app
>   server's sender ID, and the scope set to the appropriate value for GCM
>   (depending on your platform)....

It is unique to each application. Has to be..if you want to send individual notifications to each of the different applications.

Comment: Thanks your reply,I feel GCM ID need not be unique for each application because we do define a permissions for broadcast receivers in application manifest file to identify who can receive a message and who can send a message and these permissions begin with application ID, which is again unique for each application. I'm confused because if GCM ID is unique for each application then why do we define permissions in manifest.